# Gradle dependency destination on non-jar config file

Tags: gradle

I can create a dependency to something other than a jar file like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile files("../other-project/config.txt")
}
```

The above works fine, except that config.txt ends up in the WEB-INF/lib folder of my war file. Instead I need it to be in WEB-INF/classes in the war file, and in src/main/resources for jettyRun.

How can I control where the dependency ends up? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

I can also solve this with a copy task, but this really is a dependency in that I don't need the file updated unless it changes. An unconditional copy would work, but I'd rather do this the right way.

Comment: @Gerhard, I appreciate your efforts, but you've edited my question to one of your choosing and then proceeded to answer your question, not mine. As it happens, "other-project" in my example is not a gradle build, but just happens to be where the other file lives, so your answer doesn't apply.

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood you question and assumed that other-project was a Gradle project too. I'll edit my answer. I've also rolled back the changed title.

Comment: Thanks to you both, but if I understand your posts, neither answers my question. I asked about getting gradle to treat the external file as a dependency, in the sense of "go get a fresh copy of this file only if it has been updated". I suspect it's not worth it to worry over this.

Comment: See below for my simple solution.

Comment: Fred, can you get what you want by declaring a new configuration that will include all resources that should get copied to these non-standard directories, and then use Peter's `war { into()` approach to copy only the resources associated with that configuration into those non-standard locations?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have configured a multi-project build with the following directory and file structure:

```
/combined-war
    /main-project
        /src
            /webapp
                /WEB-INF
                    web.xml
        build.gradle
    /other-project
        /resources
            /WEB-INF
                /classes
                    config.txt
        build.gradle
    build.gradle
```

In order to allow `jettyRun` to combine the contents of the `webapp` directory from `main-project` with the contents of the `resources` directory in `other-project` you need to add a workaround to your `build.gradle` of `main-project` (I've adapted the one posted by the user [siasia on gist](https://gist.github.com/siasia/1618850)).

Adding the same directory content to the war file is quite simple and is documented in the [Gradle User Guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html) and and the [DSL reference](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html).

```java
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

import org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.internal.JettyPluginWebAppContext

def newResourceCollection(File... resources) {
    def script = '''
        import org.mortbay.resource.ResourceCollection
        new ResourceCollection(resources)
    '''

    def shell = new GroovyShell(JettyPluginWebAppContext.class.classLoader)
    shell.setProperty("resources", resources as String[])
    return shell.evaluate(script)
}

jettyRun.doFirst {
    jettyRun.webAppConfig = new JettyPluginWebAppContext()
    jettyRun.webAppConfig.baseResource = newResourceCollection(
        // list the folders that should be combined
        file(webAppDirName),
        file("${project(':other-project').projectDir}/resources")
    )
}

war {
    from("${project(':other-project').projectDir}/resources")
}
```

Whenever you execute `gradle jettyRun` a new `ResourceCollection` is created that combines the given directories. Per default Jetty locks (at least on Windows) all the files it's serving. So, in case you want to edit those files while Jetty is running take a look at the [following solutions](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Fix_file_locking_problem_with_jettyrun).

**Update**

Since `other-project` in this case is not another Gradle project the two tasks in `build.gradle` should look like that:

```java
jettyRun.doFirst {
    jettyRun.webAppConfig = new JettyPluginWebAppContext()
    jettyRun.webAppConfig.baseResource = newResourceCollection(
        file(webAppDirName),
        file("$projectDir/../other-project/resources")
    )
}

war {
    from("$projectDir/../other-project/resources")
}
```

I'm not aware of any solution that adds only one file (e.g. `config.txt`). You'll always have to add a complete directory.

Answer (score 1):

The `war` task (as configured by the `war` plugin) puts dependencies into `WEB-INF/lib`, the web project's own code/resources into `WEB-INF/classes`, and web app content (which by default goes into `src/main/webapp`) into `WEB-INF`. Other content can be added by explicitly configuring the `war` task. For example:

```
war {
    into("WEB-INF/classes") {
        from "../other-project/config.txt"
    }
}
```

One way to make this work with embedded Jetty (though maybe not the most convenient during development) is to use `jettyRunWar` instead of `jettyRun`. Another solution that comes to mind, particularly if the content to be added resides in its own directory, is to declare that directory as an additional resource directory of the web project (`sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir "../other-project/someResourceDir"`). This is in fact an alternative to configuring the `war` task. If the web project already has a dependency on the other project, you could instead configure an additional resource directory for that project.

Comment: I like the simplicity of your solution. Works like a charm. When you don't need Jetty to hot deploy changes in the additional resource directory that's probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned above, it's simple enough to do an unconditional copy that solves the problem. Again, not the question I originally asked. But here's my solution that works for both war and jettyRun tasks:

```
processResources.doFirst {
    copy {
        from '../other-project/config.txt'
        into 'src/main/resources'
    }
}
```